# How to bring image from url

Tags: django, html, image, url

When you share a link on Facebook, it displays an image from that webpage. How can I add that functionality to a forum I have?. I use django (but I am not sure if this matters).

Comment: Are you able to use php?

Comment: On the server side, you'll have to call the page identified by the link and scrape the returned HTML to look for images. You will need some pretty good logic to identify meaningless icons versus meaningful images to use.

Comment: Use OG in your template

Comment: He would use OG tags for a site like Facebook to read metadata from HIS site, but that's not what he's asking for. He needs to be the one that gathers the info from another site. OG seems to be the right standard to use, so he could search for OG tags in the page that someone is linking to, but there's no guarantee there will be any.

Comment: @BrianStephens Thanks for helping me explain the question.

Comment: @SpencerMay I am not good in php. If anyone knows a Python library that could be useful in this case I would appreciate the share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a good article explaining a sample algorithm for finding the "best" image to represent an external webpage. It checks for the OG (Open Graph) tags that @petkostas mentioned, if the external page happens to use them. Otherwise, it looks for images on its own.

https://tech.shareaholic.com/2012/11/02/how-to-find-the-image-that-best-respresents-a-web-page/

Answer (score 1):

There is an API called **thumbalizr**. https://api.thumbalizr.com/

It's quite simple to use, you give it the URL and the width of the img. It gets you the thumbnail.

I bet there's many similar tools, but this seems to be one of the most popular.

**EDIT:**

1. Write a script which would add your desired URL to this link `https://api.thumbalizr.com/?url=URL_HERE`
2. Get screenshot capture status using HTTP header (X-Thumbalizr-Status) from the link you just created.
3. According to it's status show the screenshot or show that it's still loading in your UI.

Comment: Tony, I need a way to do this dynamically on a forum I have. I don't  think this online app can serve that purpose.

Comment: Note that I did not suggest you using the online tool, I suggested that you should use the API.

Thumbalizr API takes URL and gets Image.

1. Write a script which would add your desired URL to this link `https://api.thumbalizr.com/?url=URL_HERE`
2. Get screenshot capture status using HTTP header (X-Thumbalizr-Status) from the link you just created.
3. According to it's status show the screenshot or show that it's still loading in your UI.

More details here: https://api.thumbalizr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses OG for sharing, use the image tag of OG in your template. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content
Use an empty block in your template:

```
{% block opengraph %}{% endblock opengraph %}
```